# Kendo Template using kendoNumericTextBox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-template

Im using kendo template popup for my grid editing and I want to use `kendoNumericTextBox` for input validate, any idea how to do? [DEMO DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYUYIBaC/6)

```
$('#percentage').kendoNumericTextBox({
    spinners: false,
    restrictDecimals: true,
    round: false
});
```

Comment: is this what you are after? https://dojo.telerik.com/IYUYIBaC/10

Comment: @DavidShorthose i add `data-format="#"` and give me error. Any idea why? I do not want any decimal value.

Comment: so `#` in the kendo templating world is a special character and needs to be escaped by using `\\` so for your example you would need to do `data-format="\\#"`

Answer (score 1):

format: "c0" is the right format

```
$("#percentage").kendoNumericTextBox({
   format: "c0"
});
```

[Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/configuration/format)